# Nef and effective cone of minimal conic bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, ample-bundles

Let $\pi: S\to C$ be a minimal conic bundle over a field $k$ of characteristic zero. That is, $S$ is a geometrically irreducible smooth surface with Picard rank $2$ and $C$  a geometrically irreducible smooth curve over $k$ and each fiber of $\pi$ is isomorphic to a plane conic. Is there an explicit description of the nef and ample cone of $S$? If not in general, maybe when $C=\mathbb{P}^1_k$?

Comment: There is some discussion of nef and effective cones on ruled surfaces in Lazarsfeld's *Positivity in algebraic geometry I*, §1.5A. I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but I this is not exactly what I need. Note that $\pi$ can have some reducible fibers whereas in Lazarsfeld all fibers are a $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: Note that if the Picard rank of $S$ is 2, then $\pi$ cannot have any reducible fibres.

Comment: You are right. What I meant is that there can be fibers that are not geometrically irreducible (I am not working over an algebraically closed field).